# Remove box and shadow - point wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am facing issues while modifying the layout of my current website.  Actually i dont need the box and shadow.

I tried the following code but still it does not solve my purpose.

```
box-shadow: none !important;
```

For your reference :

My wordpress theme : POINT

My website link : http://selfarena.com/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where did yo u applied this css?

Comment: @era : i removed it as it does not work

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main-container {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

add this in your css. it should work.

Comment: It worked like charm.  Can you tell me how to make the header background full width please

Comment: header is currently based in `main-container`. to make it full you need to put it before starting `main-container`. then remove `max-width` from header css

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you suggest a way to change the background color of header to white, so that it feels like full width.

Comment: `.site-branding {background: none;}`

Comment: if my answer have solved your purpose then mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank you so much now the background color is changed.  Can you please tell me how to remove the lines which are in between menu items.

Comment: not sure but this should work `#navigation > ul li  a {border:0 !important}`

Comment: It worked.  Thank you so much Era.  Your assistance is very much appreciated.  Thanks again.